# Negotiating the intellectual property of a (US) industry contract

Tags: industry, legal-issues, intellectual-property, contract

I'm finishing a post-doc and possibly going (back into) industry, but with the intent to continue research and publish papers and FOSS software.

I know that hi-tech companies typically give you this agreement to sign about them having all intellectual property rights and you having nothing - a Properitary Information Agreement.

Luckily, in my case, I'm more-or-less the first proper hire of a professional employee (it's a start-up); and the company is positive about me doing research and about them releasing (some/lots) of FOSS. So that means that there's room for negotiations.

I haven't gotten a draft of this agreement yet, but I wanted to draw on people's experience and ask: What's important to put in, and to leave out, from such an agreement? Are there particular issues I should keep an eye for to not get "burned" by understanding things one way and the company understanding them another way?

Notes:

- The field is applied computer science.
- It's a US company, operating in Texas but registered in Delaware.

Comment: This depends a lot in which jurisdiction you are in. Without knowing that nobody can give you a good answer.

Comment: @AttilaKinali: See edit.

Comment: The state may also matter.

Comment: @mkennedy: Ok, state of operation and incorporation too.